# yocto sunxi machine name

Tags: yocto, bitbake, nanopi

While running nanopi-neo image in yocto it throws the following error.
In local.conf MACHINE ??= "nanopi-neo

ERROR:  OE-core's config sanity checker detected a potential misconfiguration.
    Either fix the cause of this error or at your own risk disable the checker (see sanity.conf).
    Following is the list of potential problems / advisories:

```
MACHINE=nanopi-neo is invalid. Please set a valid MACHINE in your local.conf, environment or other configuration file.
```

Can anyone please tell me to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, **nanopi-neo** is unknown target device for your setup.
*MACHINE ??= nanopi-neo* looks as default value, so you most probably should set this variable to the target that is available in your bsp layer, which typically has name **meta-bsp-*smth***. You can find the list of available devices in  **meta-bsp-*smth*/conf/machine** folder (e.g. **meta-bsp-*smth*/conf/machine/some_dev_name.conf**). Then add to local.conf:

```
MACHINE ?= "some_dev_name"
```

Check also in **conf/bblayers.conf** which layers are enabled if error remains, that bsp layer's full path should be in the list of **BBLAYERS**.

## Update

You can also check available products by running

```
# bitbake-layers show-products
```

and check the first column for availability and correct name of product. Then, available layers you can check by running:

```
# bitbake-layers show-layers
```

and check if **meta-sunxi** is in the output list.

Comment: Yes thanks for your reply but in meta-sunxi/conf/machine the following conf files are available.cubieboard2.conf,**nanopi-neo-air.conf**,**nanopi-neo.conf**,cubieboard2.conf,cubieboard.conf.    So even after choosing the nanopi-neo or nanopi-neo-air the above mentioned error is throwing.

Comment: Sometimes I get same issue even if configuration file exists. It probably occurs when the `local.conf` configuration is updated in an unexpected way. In this specific case, just remove your build directory and source your the environment again. Then, update your local.conf again. It should be fine..

Comment: @MohammedHarris could you attach your local.conf ??

Comment: Same error it is throwing even after changing to new build directory also.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add meta-sunxi to your layermix.

```
git clone git://git.yoctoproject.org/poky
cd poky
git clone git://github.com/linux-sunxi/meta-sunxi
. ./oe-init-build-env
bitbake-layers add-layer ../meta-sunxi
MACHINE=nanopi-neo-air bitbake core-image-minimal
```

you can bitbake any image you like, if you want to not use
MACHINE on cmdline it can be added to local.conf for persistence

`MACHINE = "nanopi-neo-air"`